# Why am I getting cached responses from my web API until I stop and start IIS website

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, caching, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple web API for getting data from a database. The responses are retrieved using Entity Framework, mapped with Automapper, and returned as JSON.

I was doing some testing and I noticed something weird. I changed a column value in the database, but when I polled the API with a GET, I got the old value. I guess it's cached somewhere, so I made use of the fact that IE is a browser with a clean slate and checked the response in there, which was the same. After some digging, I noticed that I can force an updated response by stopping and then starting the website in IIS manager. Curiously, just clicking ``restart'' apparently does not have the same effect.

Relevant headers:

```
Cache-Control → no-cache
Date → Wed, 26 Aug 2015 08:41:30 GMT
Expires → -1
Pragma → no-cache
Server → Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version → 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By → ASP.NET
```

I tried it with both enabled and disabled output cache in IIS, with no difference. Also, when I modify the data through the API, it's reflected in the next GET just fine.

So, I have two questions: First, why is the response cached, and less importantly, what does stop+start do that restart does not?

Comment: the date should change and make a cache update

Comment: Is your Entity Framework DataContext instantiated as singleton ? If so, it  may be the cause of the problem.